# Is there a way to pickle objects so that in separate run to retrieve them

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I wonder if it is possible somehow to read the pickle file correctly without providing MyClass code.

```py
import pickle


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._n = n

    def give_vec(self):
        return [1 for _ in range(self._n)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MyClass(30)

    with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as p:
        pickle.dump(m, p)
```

Assume we have run the code above and now start a python interpreter and try the following

```py
>>> import pickle
>>> p = open('test.pickle', 'rb')
>>> a = pickle.load(p)
```

So that we won't get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MyClass' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

The idea is to provide a pickle that has some interface without specifying the exact class

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible *with pickle alone.*

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-picklable:

> Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.

So it is only possible to pickle data, not the behavior of the associated classes.

**But** you can use [dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill):

> dill can be used to store python objects to a file, but the primary usage is to send python objects across the network as a byte stream. dill is quite flexible, and allows arbitrary user defined classes and functions to be serialized.

Just replace `import pickle` with `import dill as pickle`, and it will work:

```
import dill as pickle


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._n = n

    def give_vec(self):
        return [1 for _ in range(self._n)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MyClass(30)

    with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as p:
        pickle.dump(m, p)
```

```
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> p = open('test.pickle', 'rb')
>>> a = pickle.load(p)
>>> a
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7eff33758340>
```

Comment: I've added a solution with third-party library `dill`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just noticed that in the code where I define MyClass when I replace pickle with cloudpickle it works.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info! I didn't know cloudpickle before. Nice to see that there's multiple options to choose form.